# Dynamic Pivot Grouping by Case (Unpivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok I have a situation here: I created a table and inserted some values:

```
CREATE TABLE temp1
(
ProcessName varchar(50),
ProcessNo  varchar(50),
ProcessPages varchar(50),
ProcessClass varchar (50)
)

INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','5','O');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','4','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','10','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','7','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','6','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','14','K');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','23','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','45','L');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','52','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','3','K');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','T');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','6','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','H');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','8','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','T');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','2','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','3','T');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','3','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','5','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','10','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','15','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','25','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','35','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','45','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','55','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','25','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','25','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','20','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','3','O');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','3','K');
```

I am trying to come out with this desired result.

```
|       | With Y        | Without Y
|1p     | 5             | 8        
|2p     | 6             | 0
|3p     | 1             | 1
|4p     | 7             | 1
|5p     | 2             | 0  
|Total  | 21            | 10
```

The With_y is WHERE [ProcessClass]='Y' and the Without_Y is WHERE [ProcessClass]<>'Y'

I have a code below:

```
DECLARE  @ColumnNames1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnNames1=Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename([ProcessName])
                   FROM temp1
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
SET @SQL1= '
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [ProcessName], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >=  1 and [ProcessPages] <=  5 THEN ''1p'' END) AS [1p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >=  6 and [ProcessPages] <= 10 THEN ''2p'' END) AS [2p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >= 11 and [ProcessPages] <= 16 THEN ''3p'' END) AS [3p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >= 17 and [ProcessPages] <= 50 THEN ''4p'' END) AS [4p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >  50 THEN ''5p'' END) AS [5p],
        COUNT([ProcessName]) AS Total
    FROM temp1
    WHERE [ProcessClass]=''Y'' 
    GROUP BY [ProcessName]) AS SOURCE
    UNPIVOT ( val FOR [''] IN ([1p],[2p],[3p],[4p],[5p],[Total]) ) U
    PIVOT ( MAX(val) FOR [ProcessName] IN('+@ColumnNames1 +') ) As PivotTable'

    --print @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL1
```

This returns:

How Can I make it achieve the desired report above

Comment: Any input from anyone?

Comment: Can you edit your post and properly format the output ? I don't understand what you need in the end.

Comment: When you want tablular data formatted as a table you can select it and hit ctrl+k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you want you don't need to use dynamic SQL at all, but instead you can use a simple `group by` with `grouping sets`.

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 
       [ProcessName] =    
       CASE 
          WHEN ProcessPages >=  1 AND ProcessPages <=  5 THEN '1p' 
          WHEN ProcessPages >=  6 AND ProcessPages <= 10 THEN '2p'
          WHEN ProcessPages >= 11 AND ProcessPages <= 16 THEN '3p'
          WHEN ProcessPages >= 17 AND ProcessPages <= 50 THEN '4p'
          WHEN ProcessPages >  50                        THEN '5p' 
       END
       , ProcessClass    
    FROM temp1
)
SELECT
    ProcessName = CASE WHEN GROUPING(ProcessName) = 0 THEN ProcessName ELSE 'Total' END 
    , With_y     = COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessClass] =  'Y' THEN ProcessClass END)
    , Without_Y  = COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessClass] <> 'Y' THEN ProcessClass END)
FROM t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (ProcessName, ());

-- use the next line for versions <2008:
-- GROUP BY ProcessName WITH ROLLUP;
```

To avoid having to repeat the case expression I used a common table expression.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8792a/1)

Comment: .Grouping sets does not work on prior versions to SQL 2008. i AM ON SQL 2005. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Yaba_Middle Yes, you can use rollup instead, something like _group by processname with rollup_ should work. I'm mobile at the moment but I'll update my answer later.

Comment: @Yaba_Middle I don't have access to any 2005?server, but I think rollup should work; see this fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8792a/1

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your list of categories is dynamic so there's no reason for the dynamic sql or all those pivots/unpivots.

```
SELECT
        '1p ' + cast(sum(y1p) as varchar(8)) + ' ' + cast(sum(n1p) as varchar(8)) +
       ' 2p ' + cast(sum(y2p) as varchar(8)) + ' ' + cast(sum(n2p) as varchar(8)) +
       ' 3p ' + cast(sum(y3p) as varchar(8)) + ' ' + cast(sum(n3p) as varchar(8)) +
       ' 4p ' + cast(sum(y4p) as varchar(8)) + ' ' + cast(sum(n4p) as varchar(8)) +
       ' 5p ' + cast(sum(y5p) as varchar(8)) + ' ' + cast(sum(n5p) as varchar(8)) +
    ' Total ' + cast(sum(ty)  as varchar(8)) + ' ' + cast(sum(tn)  as varchar(8)) 
FROM (
    SELECT ProcessName, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass  = 'Y' and ProcessPages between  1 and  5 THEN 1 END) AS y1p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass  = 'Y' and ProcessPages between  6 and 10 THEN 1 END) AS y2p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass  = 'Y' and ProcessPages between 11 and 16 THEN 1 END) AS y3p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass  = 'Y' and ProcessPages between 17 and 50 THEN 1 END) AS y4p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass  = 'Y' and ProcessPages > 50 THEN 1 END) AS y5p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass <> 'Y' and ProcessPages between  1 and  5 THEN 1 END) AS n1p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass <> 'Y' and ProcessPages between  6 and 10 THEN 1 END) AS n2p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass <> 'Y' and ProcessPages between 11 and 16 THEN 1 END) AS n3p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass <> 'Y' and ProcessPages between 17 and 50 THEN 1 END) AS n4p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass <> 'Y' and ProcessPages > 50 THEN 1 END) AS n5p,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass  = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS ty,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessClass <> 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS tn
    FROM temp1
    GROUP BY ProcessName
) AS SOURCE
```

Note that you've edited your desired output format since I posted this.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know you were on it.

Comment: It's ok. Just a reminder to be very careful in describing what you want. I got them impression that it was important to you to have the output on a single line.